# Redirect to the starting page after getting a token

Tags: angular, authentication

When I load my Angular page, it should go to a site, get a token and redirect to the same page. How do I achieve this?

I thought of calling `window.location.href = get-token-site.com/token?state=link-to-my-site.com` in ngOnInit()

But, This will make an infinite loop and goes back and forth. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: You can try to get your token using an ajax call, look at the Angular's HttpClient module.

Comment: @BogdanC The Token generator site is OAuth Authentication enabled site with CORS. When I call the token provider site, It again redirects to another page to get token. Moreover, the server won't allow the link which is not in `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. If I try to access it like `window.location.href`, I don't have any problem. So my chances are few and I am restricted to only use pure Angular.

Answer (score 0):

you can use regular expresions to check if the url have a token or not

for example:

```
const url = window.location.href;
const haveNoToken = /^https?:\/\/stackoverflow.com\/?$/.test(url);
if (haveNoToken) {
    window.location.href = get-token-site.com/token?state=link-to-my-site.com;
}
```

so you avoid the infinite loop

Comment: Thanks, your idea sounds good. However, after getting the first token, it will expire soon and I have to reload the page to get the new token. Now the condition won't enter if statement right? to get a new token?

Comment: you can save the token in the url in local storage, so you keep your last token, so if the token you read from the url is not equal ti the local storage you execute the href

Comment: you can readed from the url with '''window.location.search.substr(1)''', if you handled just one GET variable. And save in local storage '''localStorage.token = 'this is your token'   '''

Comment: No, every time I call the token generator site it will give me a new Token. It doesn't matter whether the old one got expired or not. I thought of using the same token till it dies. I can have another control statement to check the token validity and get a new one. Thanks for your input!.

Comment: I can't understand how this regex work ` /^https?:\/\/stackoverflow.com\/?$/.test(url)`. Can you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

Reditrect to another site :

Keep this statement in your angular page :

HTML:

```
<button (click)="getTokenFromAnotherSite()">Get Token</buttom>
```

TS:

```
getTokenFromAnotherSite(){
 window.location.href = `path to another site from where you want to get token?returnPath ='return_page_path'`;
}
```

On another site component.ts:

```
/**
   * Method initializes first.
   */
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(resp => {
      this.returnUrl= resp.returnPath ;

    });

  if(gotToken){
    window.location.href = `you_host/${this.returnUrl}?token=gotToken`;
    }
  }
```

Receive Token in your same angular page :

```
/**
   * Method initializes first.
   */
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(resp => {
      this.token = resp.token;
    });
  }
```

Comment: where do I call this `window.location.href = path to another site;`? I dont want user to click anywhere. It should automatically redirect to the token page when my angular page loads

Comment: As a understood you words "When I load my Angular page, it should go to a site, get a token and redirect to the same page.".am i correct??

Comment: In which function should I place this `window.location.href = path to another site from where you want to get token?returnPath =your return page url;` in `ngOnInit()`?

Comment: see edited one.  you can place it any where as per your project requirement.

Comment: I already have this method implemented. I want to get a token when the page loads. Its like automatically getting token without clicking any button. I have mentioned that in my first comment. Anyway, thanks for your help.